# How to set multiline to lable on tablviewcell , cell is subtitile have two buttons on it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

Hello, I want to set `UITableViewCell` label to have multiple 
      lines. I have label with two buttons on it , i set 
      numberoflines to 0 & also set height for cell but
      it's not working the label text goes out to button, can
      anyone help me in this please , here is code for 
      `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for setting lines

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
   }
```

and code for `heightForRowAtIndexPath` of cell set the size of label

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       NSString *cellText = [_eventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" 
       size:18];
       CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
       CGRect textRect = [cellText boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cellFont}
       context:nil];
       CGSize size = textRect.size;
       return size.height + 40;
}
```

please see above image. thanks.

Comment: are you using autolayouts

Comment: then use autolayouts

Comment: your problem is label text is going on buttons right?

Comment: yes i set numberoflines but was not worked @Maheshreddy

Comment: you dont know the Autolayouts?

Comment: yay i know auto-layout but i put label & button programmatically on cell how i do auto-layout on this?? @Maheshreddy

Comment: ok fine.give label width as   [x,y,view.size.width-40(required),height]

Comment: you need give some space for trailing then it will work as u want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105357/discussion-between-ihappy-and-mahesh-reddy).

Comment: @Maheshreddy thnx for help its working

Answer (score 0):

Just put a trailing constraint to you UILabel margining the buttons with whatever constant you want. If you're using Auto Layout.

If you're not using Auto Layout just try to the Autoresizing mask from you xib file. Make sure that the width of your label is not overlapping with your buttons. Make the margin a bit further.

Comment: no autolayout is not used , can you help how i do this @Ashraf Tawfeeq

Comment: i set label & button all programmatically on table cell how i do auto-layout in this @Ashraf

Comment: Don't add the buttons on UILabel. Add your UILabel and the buttons on the ContainerView.

Comment: have any e.g or link of ContainerView @Ashraf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105355/discussion-between-ihappy-and-ashraf-tawfeeq).